# Flipping frequency visualization - Java - Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm completely new to coding, literally just screwing around with things whilst, and, at the same time, trying to learn.

First:

So, I have a chunk of code which helps me visualize frequency from an audio track. Simply, I just want to know how to flip the visualization from left to right and from right to left. In the code, I'm trying to flip top left and bottom left.

Second:

Also, if anyone knows like to extend the visualization length all the way to the edge of the sketch.

And just in general, if you can explain to me why and how, whatever the solution might be here to learn. Much appreciated for the help in advance.

This is the bit of code which I want to flip.

```
for(int i = 0; i < song.left.size() - 1; i++)
{
    //TOP - LEFT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 - fft.getBand(i)*4);

    //Bottom - RIGHT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 + fft.getBand(i)*4);
```

The whole sketch:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;
FFT fft;

void setup()
{
  size(1024, 512, P3D);

  minim = new Minim(this);

  song = minim.loadFile("mysong.mp3", 1024);
  song.play();

  fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  fft.forward(song.mix);

  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  for (int i = 0; i < fft.specSize (); i = i+10) // i+10 Controls a sequence of repeated 

  {
    //TOP - RIGHT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 - fft.getBand(i)*4);

    //Bottom - LEFT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 + fft.getBand(i)*4);

    //TOP - LEFT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 - fft.getBand(i)*4);

    //Bottom - RIGHT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 + fft.getBand(i)*4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: All code UNTESTED**

```java
// this is drawing one line from center of screen 
// to (top of screen - frequency) 
// returned from a specific "slot"in fft via fft.getBand(i)

line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 - fft.getBand(i)*4);

// note that fft.getBand(i) is multiplied by 4. this is your range, 
// increase that number and lines will be bigger


// the next line does the same but towards the bottom of screen
// note th '+' instead of '-''
// so if you want to keep them with the same range you gotta change here as well
// better, make a range var..
line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 + fft.getBand(i)*4);
```

You have a loop that gets every band from fft and draws one line for each one (actually two, one up and one down). The order of the frequency visualisation is given by the order that you go trough fft. Now you are going from 0 until the length of fft list.
Go backwards and the draw will be flipped:

```
 // from end to begin...
 for (int i = fft.specSize()-1 ; i > 0; i-=10) 

  {
    //TOP - RIGHT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 - fft.getBand(i)*4);

    //Bottom - LEFT
    line(i/2+width/2, height/2, i/2+width/2, height/2 + fft.getBand(i)*4);
  }
```

Alternatively yo can use [scale(-1, 0)](http://processing.org/reference/scale_.html) to flip horizontally your screen… Then you can further control transformations with `push/popMatrix()`

HTH